# Swagger Project Create command line error

Tags: mongodb, express, command, swagger, git-bash

I've done some searching, but there doesn't seem to be too much related to Swagger here (and nothing I've found related to my problem).

I am trying to create a new Swagger project, with Swagger creating and managing my routes/endpoints.  However, when I try to create the project from scratch using "swagger project create projectName" in the command line, I am getting the following error;

$ swagger project create projectName

- ? Framework?
- connect
- express
- hapi
- restify
- sails [SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.{1.0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier.]

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this error or knows how to fix it?  I just started coding 6 months ago, so I'm still a pretty big newb - so if you can keep explanations/solutions simple that would be great (my programming vocabulary is pretty weak, lol).

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm having the same issue... did you found the reason?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this!  I don't think I ever figured it out - I was working on a side project and ultimately moved on to another side project :-/

Answer (score 2):

This issue is probably due to you using swagger in Windows.

If you come across this same issue you can simply add the -f flag and choose the framework you want to swagger with ;)

```
swagger project create -f express file-name
```

Beyond this simple workaround, this is what you find at the [swagger github repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#windows-note):

For some versions of npm on Windows will have problems on the npm install step of swagger project create. They are related to a debug module on npm not being managed properly. The following steps should resolve this issue:

In the project directory, execute the following commands:

```
npm install yamljs

npm install debug

npm install swagger-tools
```